# Fibonacci and the spreading of viruses

Tags: sequences-and-series, exponential-function, mathematical-modeling, biology

I tried to understand better the spreading of a virus on a case-by-case basis, not by differential or difference equations as in [SIR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compartmental_models_in_epidemiology#The_SIR_model) and [SEIR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compartmental_models_in_epidemiology#The_SEIR_model) models with possibly non-integer rates and time constants.

In the course of this, Fibonacci numbers showed up in a – for me – unexpected way. And a relation between Fibonacci numbers and powers of $2$ showed up that I'd like to understand better.

This was my approach. Let $\lambda$ be the [pre-infectious (or latent) period](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Latent_period_(epidemiology)), and let $\lambda = 1$ (e.g. $1$ day). Let $\delta$ be the duration of infectiousness, e.g. $\delta = 4$. After $\lambda + \delta$ days, an infected individual recovers. Finally let $\beta$ be the infection rate, i.e. the number of people an infectious individual infects per day. Let $\beta = 1$. This choice of $\beta$ and $\delta$ corresponds to a basic reproduction number $R_0 = \beta\cdot\delta = 4$.

In a deterministic and idealized setup the number of infected indiviudals $I$ evolves like this starting with a single patient 0, neglecting the effect of the decreasing number of susceptible individuals:

```
    1  1  1  1  1                        (patient 0)
       1  1  1  1  1                     (patient 1)
          2  2  2  2  2                  (patients 2 and 3)
             4  4  4  4   4              (patients 4 to  7)
                8  8  8   8   8          (patients 8 to 15)
                  15 15  15  15  15      ...
                     29  29  29  29  29  ...
                         56  56  56  56  ...
                            108 108 108  ...
                                208 208  ...
I = 1  2  4  8 16 30 58 112 216 416 ...
∆ =                2  6  16  40  96 ...
```

Obviously, $I(t) = 2^t$ when  $t < \lambda + \delta$. For $t \ge \lambda + \delta$, $I(t)$ deviates from $2^t$, in this example by

```
∆ = 2, 6, 16, 40, 96, 222, 502, 1116, 2448, 5312, 11426, 24398, 51776, 109296, 229664, 480670
```

which is a sequence not to be found at [OEIS](http://oeis.org/search?q=2%2C%206%2C%2016%2C%2040%2C%2096%2C%20222%2C%20502%2C%201116%2C%202448%2C%205312%2C%2011426%2C%2024398%2C%2051776%2C%20109296%2C%20229664%2C%20480670), but I guess it's the number of binary strings of length $n$ having at least one run of length at least $5$ (see below).

For the sake of comparison here for $\delta = 2$

```
    1  1  1                   
       1  1  1                    
          2  2  2                 
             3  3  3              
                5  5  5          
                   8  8  8
                     13 13  13   
                        21  21  21   
                            34  34 34
                                55 55 ...
I = 1  2  4  6 10 16 26 42  68 110 ...
∆ =          2  6 16 38 86 188 402 ...
```

<sup>*[I(n) is obviously twice the $n$-th Fibonacci number. The Fibonacci numbers come also as the numbers of newly infected individuals per day – but only in this very special case $\delta = 2$. According to [OEIS](https://oeis.org/search?q=%202%2C%206%2C%2016%2C%2038%2C%2086%2C%20188%2C402), the sequence $\Delta$ gives the **number of $n$-tosses having a run of $3$ or more heads or a run of $3$ or more tails for a fair coin** resp. **the difference between the number of branches of a complete binary tree of $n$ levels, and the number of recursive calls needed to compute the $(n+1)$-th Fibonacci number**.]*</sup>

And for $\delta = 3$:

```
    1  1  1  1                         
       1  1  1  1                    
          2  2  2  2                   
             4  4  4  4               
                7  7  7  7            
                  13 13 13  13        
                     24 24  24  24    
                        44  44  44  44 
                            81  81  81 ...
                               149 149 ...
I = 1  2  4  8 14 26 48 88 162 298 ...
∆ =             2  6 16 40  94 214 ...
```

<sup>*[According to [OEIS](https://oeis.org/search?q=2%2C%206%2C%2016%2C%2040%2C%2094%2C%20214%2C%20476%2C%201040%2C%202242%2C%204782%2C%2010112%2C%2021232%2C%2044318%2C%2092046%2C%20190364%2C%20392264%2C%20805746%2C%201650518%2C%203372816), the sequence $\Delta$ gives the **number of binary strings of length n having at least one run of length at least 4**.]*</sup>

I am looking for a general formula

> $I_{\lambda\delta\beta}(t) = 2^t - \Delta_{\lambda\delta\beta}(t)$

relating in the special case of $\lambda = \beta = 1$ and $\delta =2$ the Fibonacci numbers with the powers of $2$.

A specific side question:

> **What has the number of recursive calls needed to compute the $n$-th
> Fibonacci number to do with the number of binary strings of length $n$
> having at least one run of length at least $3$?** (see above)

---

For $\lambda = \beta = 1$ and large $\delta$, e.g. $\delta =20$, the first non-zero terms of $\Delta_{\lambda\delta\beta}$ are

```
∆ = 2, 6, 16, 40, 96, 224, 512, 1152, 2560, 5632, 12288, 26624, 57344, 122880, 262144, 557056, 1179648, 2490368, 5242880, 11010048
```

which is the initial part of the sequence $a(n) = n\cdot 2^{n-2}$ (see [OEIS](https://oeis.org/search?q=2%2C%206%2C%2016%2C%2040%2C%2096%2C%20224%2C%20512%2C%201152%2C%202560%2C%205632%2C%2012288%2C%2026624%2C%2057344%2C%20122880%2C%20262144%2C%20557056%2C%201179648%2C%202490368%2C%205242880%2C%2011010048)).

---

**Edit 1**: The [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalizations_of_Fibonacci_numbers#Higher_orders), user @heropup provided, yields this insight:

[image]

**Edit 2**: There is a follow-up question to this one: [Fibonacci and tossing coins](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3749177/fibonacci-and-tossing-coins).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the case where $\lambda = \beta = 1$, and $\delta$ is the only free parameter, the leading diagonal in your table is given by the $\delta$-step recurrence relation $$a_t = \sum_{k=1}^\delta a_{t-k},$$ with initial conditions $$a_k = \begin{cases}0, & k < 0, \\ 1, & k = 0 . \end{cases}$$  This is a generalization of the familiar Fibonacci sequence.  Then $$I_t = \sum_{k=0}^{\delta} a_{t-k} = a_{t+1} + a_{t-\delta}$$ and $$\Delta_t = 2^t - I_t = 2^t - (a_{t+1} + a_{t-\delta}).$$  Consequently, a closed form solution for $a_t$ would yield the desired sequences.  [This is given by the formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalizations_of_Fibonacci_numbers#Higher_orders) $$a_t = \left[\frac{r_\delta^{t-1} (r_\delta-1)}{(\delta+1)r_\delta-2\delta}\right],$$ where $[ \cdot ]$ denotes the nearest integer function (i.e., rounding), and $r_\delta$ is the real root of the polynomial $$z^{\delta+1} - 2z^\delta + 1 = 0$$ that is nearest in value to $2$.  Therefore, the computation of $a_t$ for large values of $t$ relies on a high-precision computation of the value of this root.  This is feasible via Newton's method with initial guess $z_0 = 2$:  $$z_{k+1} = z_k - \frac{z_k^{\delta+1} - 2z_k^\delta + 1}{(\delta+1)z_k^\delta - 2\delta z_k^{\delta-1}} = \frac{z_k (2 + \delta(z_k-2) - z_k^{-\delta})}{z_k + \delta(z_k-2)}.$$
It is worth noting that since $r_\delta = 2 - \epsilon$ with $\epsilon > 0$ for sufficiently large $\delta$, that $$a_t \approx (2-\epsilon)^{t-1} \frac{1-\epsilon}{2-\epsilon(\delta+1)},$$ thus is approximately exponential with constant of proportionality $$C = \frac{1-\epsilon}{2-\epsilon(\delta+1)} \to \frac{1}{2}.$$  One might explore the asymptotic behavior of $C$ as a function of $\delta$ more precisely.

As even this single-parameter case is not particularly tractable, I have little hope that the general case for $\beta$ and $\lambda$ will be any better.  This is why discrete-time difference equations are not as commonly used in models.  The analogous differential equation is more tractable, and when discretized, makes for roughly equivalent behavior in most cases.

Comment: Thanks for this elaborate answer! How long did it take you to write it? One question: What exactly do you mean by "discretizing the differential equations"? Doesn't this mean to have discrete time steps again?

Comment: @Hans-PeterStricker Honestly it did not take very long to answer the question; most of the effort was in checking the equations for correctness by programming in *Mathematica*.  As for "discretizing," what I mean is something far more crude--to simply take the continuous-time system and give the nearest rounded value at each discrete time step.

Comment: Maybe you want to have a look at this [related question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3747400/an-unexpected-pair-of-almost-fibonacci-and-tribonacci-series).