# An unexpected pair of almost-Fibonacci and Tribonacci series

Tags: sequences-and-series, discrete-mathematics, recurrence-relations, biology

I use a modification of the SEIR model of epidemic spread which yields - for me totally out of the blue - for special parameters an astoninglishly good approximation of the Fibonacci series with a rather well-behaved delta that initially looks like $a(n) = \sum_{k=0}^n T(k)$ where $T(n)$ are the [Tribonacci numbers](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/TribonacciNumber.html).

With

- $S$ the number of susceptible individuals
- $E$ the number of exposed individuals
- $I$ the number of infectious individuals
- $R$ the number of recovered individuals
- $P = S + E + I + R$ the total size of the population
- $\lambda = 1d$  the latency period, i.e. the number of days ($d$) it takes that an exposed individual becomes infectious
- $\beta = 1/d$ the infection rate, i.e. the number of individuals infected by an infectious individual per day
- $\delta = 5d$ the duration of infectiousness, i.e. an individual recovers $\lambda + \delta$ days after getting infected

In this model, the (dimensionless) basic reproduction number is $R_0 = \beta \cdot \delta = 5$.

The discrete model (with $\Delta t = 1d$) looks like this. Let $N(t) = \beta \cdot I(t-1) \cdot S(t-1) / P$ be the number of newly infected individuals at day $t$.

- $\Delta S(t) = -N(t)$
- $\Delta E(t) = N(t) - E(t-1)/\lambda$
- $\Delta I(t) = E(t-1)/\lambda - N(t - \lambda - \delta)$
- $\Delta R(t) = N(t - \lambda - \delta)$

or for $\lambda = \beta = 1$, $\delta = 5$

- $\Delta S(t) = -N(t)$
- $\Delta E(t) = N(t) - E(t-1)$
- $\Delta I(t) = E(t-1) - N(t - 6)$
- $\Delta R(t) = N(t - 6)$

with $S(0) = P - 1$, $E(0) = 1$, $I(0) = 0$, $R(0) = 0$.

The modification of the standard [SEIR model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compartmental_models_in_epidemiology#The_SEIR_model) lies in the handling of the duration of infectiousness $\delta$. Usually this is handled (just like the latency period above) as a recovering or removal rate $\nu = (\lambda + \delta)^{-1}$. In our model individuals become recovered not by rate but exactly $\lambda + \delta$ days after getting infected. This means for $\Delta I(t)$ we substract $N(t-6) = I(t-7)\cdot S(t-7)/P$ instead of $I(t-1)/6$.

This is the time series of numbers of currently infected individuals (i.e. exposed or infectious) together with their difference to the corresponding Fibonacci numbers:

```
0    1        -   1 = 0
1    1        -   1 = 0
2    2        -   2 = 0
3    2.999999 -   3 = 0.00001
4    4.999997 -   5 = 0.00003
5    7.999990 -   8 = 0.0001
6    11.99997 -  13 = 1
7    18.99992 -  21 = 2
8    29.99980 -  34 = 4
9    46.99949 -  55 = 8
10   73.99872 -  89 = 15
11   115.9967 - 144 = 28
12   181.9919 - 233 = 51
13   285.9800 - 377 = 91
```

The series of deltas [$1, 2, 4, 8, 15, 28, ... $](https://oeis.org/search?q=2%2C4%2C8%2C15%2C28) resembles the sequence $a(n) = \sum_{k=0}^n T(k)$ where $T(n)$ are the Tribonacci numbers. This might be an accident - or it has an explanation.

> For such an explanation I am looking for.

Answer (score 2):

Rounding the numbers in the second column, this makes the sequence
$$\{1,1,2,3,5,8,12,19,30,47,74,116,182,286\}$$ which is $A060961$ in $OEIS$.

According to the page, they correspond to
$$a_n=a_{n-1}+a_{n-3}+a_{n-5}\implies a_n-a_{n-1}=a_{n-3}+a_{n-5}$$

Comment: Thanks, Claude. Looking how the sequence was created (by a rather complicated set of difference equations) - does this rather simple recurrence formula make sense? Does it "explain" what happens in the first couple of steps? Note, that my sequence $1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 12, 19, 30, 47, 74, 116, 182, 286, 449, 705, 1107, 1736, 2724, 4273, 6701$ eventually deviates from the OEIS sequence $1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 12, 19, 30, 47, 74, 116, 182, 286, 449, 705, 1107, 1738, 2729, 4285 $ and finally even decays.

Comment: I just cross-checked it: When you neglect the role of susceptibles $S$ and let $N(t) = \beta\cdot I(t-1)$ then you get **exactly** the OEIS sequence A060961.