# Fibonacci and tossing coins

Tags: sequences-and-series, combinatorics

Consider the following scheme starting with a sequence $\sigma_0 = \langle 1,1,\dots,1\rangle$ of length $k$, successively followed by sequences $\sigma_i$ of the same length but shifted by one to the right, where the first entry $\sigma_{i0}$ equals the sum of all values above, and $\sigma_{ij} = \sigma_{i0}$.

For $k = 5$ one has:

```
 1  1  1  1  1                        
    1  1  1  1  1                     
       2  2  2  2  2                  
          4  4  4  4   4             
             8  8  8   8   8          
               15 15  15  15  15      
                  29  29  29  29  29  
                      56  56  56  56  56
                         108 108 108 108 108
                             208 208 208 208 208
```

Calculating the sum for each column one gets e.g. for  $k = 5$:

```
 1  2  4  8 16 30 58 112 216 416 802 1546 2980 5744 ...
```

It turns out that for $k = 3$ and $k = 4$ these sequences, namely

```
1 2 4 6 10 16 26 42 68 110 178 288 466 754 1220 1974 ...
```

and

```
1 2 4 8 14 26 48 88 162 298 548 1008 1854 3410 6272 ...
```

seem to be **the numbers of ways to toss a coin $n$ times and not get a run of $k$** (see [A128588](https://oeis.org/A128588) and [A135491](https://oeis.org/A135491)).

> **Conjecture**: This holds in general, i.e. for arbitrary $k$.

My question is two-fold:

> 1. How to prove this conjecture?
> 2. What do the schemes above have to do with tossing a coin and counting runs?

**Guess**: When you try to calculate the numbers of ways to toss a coin $n$ times and not get a run of $k$ you may come up with those schemes. But how?

---

Note that the sequence for $k=3$ ([A128588](https://oeis.org/A128588)) happens to be double the Fibonacci numbers.

The schemes arose when I tried to mimic epidemic spread in a SIR-like discrete model (see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3743545/fibonacci-and-the-spreading-of-viruses)).

Comment: These are _generating functions_, and what you've found is essentially a recursive characterization for the generating functions for runs of coins.

Comment: I've heard of generating functions and know some examples - but I would not have thought that my schemes are characterizations of generating functions. What essentially means that I have not understood what generating functions are and why and how they work. In any case: Maybe it's interesting to see how I came up with the schemes - not thinking of tossing coins and generating functions at all!

Comment: What's astounding: That a strictly deterministic process and a random process yield the very same sequence (of cases vs. of probabilities). Probabilities you get when you divide the $m$-th element by $2^m$.

Comment: @StevenStadnicki: I forgot to mention you in my comments on you comment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's another way to construct your sequence. Let $a^k$ be the sequence defined by
$$a^k_n=a^k_{n-1}+a^k_{n-2}+\cdots+a^k_{n-k+1}$$ for $n\geq k$ and
$$a^k_n=2^n$$ for $$0\leq n < k$$

Essentially this is a generalization of the fibonacci sequence where the initial terms are powers of $2$ and successive terms are the sum of the previous $k-1$ entries.

What does this have to do with coins and runs? Let's first look at the case $k=2$.
$$a^2:1,2,2,2,...,2$$
In order to create a sequence of $n$ coin flips without a run of $2$ you must first create a sequence of $n-1$ coin flips without a run of $2$, and then you are forced to pick heads or tails based on the last entry in this $n-1$ sequence.

What happens in the case $k=3$?
$$a^3:1,2,4,6,10,16,...$$
In order to count the number of ways to create a sequence of $n$ coin flips without a run of $3$, you can break this down into two easier questions: 1) How many $n$ sequences without $3$-runs have a tail of $1$-run? And 2) How many $n$ sequences without $3$-runs have a tail of $2$-runs? The respective answers are 1) the number ways you can create $n-1$ sequences without $3$-runs and 2) the number of ways to create $n-2$ sequences without $3$-runs.

In the general case, in order to count the number of $n$ sequences without a $k$-run you break the question down into a series of smaller ones: How many $n$ sequences without $k$-run have a $1$-run at the end? And so on and so forth until you ask how many $n$ sequences without $k$-runs have $k-1$ runs at the end? So counting the number of $n$ sequences without $k$-runs just amounts to summing up the previous $k-1$ terms.

If anything I've written is confusing, please let me know and I will try and explain myself better.

Comment: Thanks a lot. At first reading there's nothing confusing me, I guess I understand your derivation.